# Accessing components from game object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I am studying Unity and have a little bit of confusion. When my instructor wants to access a method from another class (such as an enemy wants access to a player method when colliding) he wrote something like this:  `other.transform.GetComponents<Player>().Damage();`

My questions are:

1. Why does he have to use `other.transform`, can he not just use
   `other.GetComponents<Player>().Damage();`
2. What are the differences between Transform and GameObject?

Answer (score 0):

As long as `other` is a GameObject, you are correct, these two function calls are essentially equivalent.

A **GameObject** is the base entity representing something that exists in world in Unity. All GameObjects have a transform. GameObjects can also have other data and behaviors associated with them through additional components, such as custom scripts, renderers, meshes, colliders, etc.

A transform is a **special type of component** that describes where a GameObject is in the world, its rotation, scale, and also provides ways to manipulate this information.

Probably at this point for legacy reasons (Unity has been around for more than ten years at this point) there are still functions on the Transform class that act on its owner GameObject, such as `GetComponents` in your example.

Comment: That whats i thought for the second question but I once saw he create an instance like this ```Transform name;``` and so what are the diff between ```GameObject name;``` and ```Transform name;```

Comment: Cool. If you want to accept and/or upvote the answer, that would be appreciated.